# How to force jQuery to add 'underline' (_) parameter to POST requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery adds a random `_` parameter when I make a `get` request:

```
function ajax( params_ )
{
    var params = params_;

    if( params[ 'data' ] == null )
    {
        params[ 'data' ] = {};
    }

    $.ajax( params );       
}
```

When I call the function with a key `method: "GET"` in params then jQuery adds the underscore parameter. In the case of `POST` it doesn't add the undescore parameter.

How to force jQuery to add the parameter in the case of `POST` request?

Comment: What do you need it for? Check `cache` parameter

Comment: @zerkms The server I request raises a error without the parameter.

Comment: What error and why does it do it?

Comment: @zerkms I don't know what error and why. I added the parameter in my Python code (instead of Javascript) and it became to work OK. But I'd like to do in in Javascript. Unforunately your advice doesn't work for post. Thank you.

Comment: "I don't know what error and why" --- so why instead of doing random stuff not get **WHY** it happens first? "Unforunately your advice doesn't work for post" --- no doubts it doesn't work - you don't know **WHAT** to fix.

Comment: @zerkms I have 2 input values for remote server. The first with parameter and the second is identical to first but without it. The first always works, the second never works. So, I know what to fix, don't I?

Comment: "So, I know what to fix" --- why does your server fire some error? There is nothing magic `_` to fail if it doesn't exist in a request. It is there in `GET` request for some important reason. It's not there in `POST` for another important reason. So, what do you want to fix then? It should work. "So, I know what to fix, don't I?" --- you told us "I don't know what error and why". So, do you?

Comment: @sergzach: Tell us more about these two inputs. Post how the requests look like, what the error that is returned states, and maybe show us your server code. Once we have identified a mistake in the erroneous request, we can fix the requesting (ajax) code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> jQuery adds a random _ parameter when I make a get request

Yes, that's for caching. Check [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **cache** (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>   Type: Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
>   HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of
>   requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
>   been requested by a GET.

> How to force jQuery to add the parameter in the case of POST request?

As the docs state, you don't need it there.

If the server *does* expect an `_` parameter, then just send it:

```
function ajax(params) {
    if (!params.data)
        params.data = {};
    if (!params.data._)
        params.data._ = "expected value";

    return $.ajax(params);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but it's irrelevant. A remote server requires the parameter. I understand, that's incorrect behaviour, but that's that.

Comment: What does the remote server need it for? What is the error when it is not there? What content should it have? Please link/post the API docs for that remote server.

Comment: I don't know. I'm not a code owner of that code. It's *private*.

Comment: @sergzach But you're getting _something_.  **Give us that something**.

Comment: The error message of the server should state it clearly. If it doesn't, contact the server developer - not us. And you should know what you're requesting from the server. Also, in case of too sparse documentation, contact the code owner.

Comment: @Bergi Pythonic `urllib` returns 10054 "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". With the parameter - it works OK.

Comment: `params._ = 'this API sucks';` <--- how about this?

Comment: @sergzach: Hm, that's not a very meaningful error message. Contact the server developer about it.

Comment: @sergzach: You must have got some documentation on how to call the api.  What does it say it requires for parameters and what does it do with them?  You can add an _ parameter as others have described, but without knowing what the server expects in that parameter you have no idea how it can affect the data returned. If you do not know that you need to contact the maintainers of the server api and get better docs (or at elast ask why they need this param and what data they expect it to contain)

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the idea! It seems, yes, my local server proxies POST javascript requests via GET. However, I don't know why a remote server requries the parameter.